# How can I fit correctly a raster plot, and change the size of the colorbar?

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster

I'm using the plot function to graph a rasterbrick thata corresponds to the precipitation in South America using R.
In order to plot it, I use the function:

```
plot(prueba,col=rev(col),breaks=brk,zlim=c(0,33),las=2,yaxt="n",xaxt="n")
axis(side=2, at=(seq(min(iy),max(iy),by=(max(iy)-min(iy))/10)), labels=paste(latsc2,"º",sep=""),las=2)
axis(side=1, at=(seq(min(jx),max(jx),by=(max(jx)-min(jx))/10)), labels=paste(lonsc2,"º",sep=""),las=2)
```

But the map I get as an output is the following:

[image]

The first thing I was wondering is if there's any way of getting rid of the white strips on the sides of the plot.

Also, I wanted to know how to resize the colorbar in order to make it easier to read. Everything I've tried to solve this problems has done no difference.

Would really appreciate any insights!

EDIT

The oputput for dput I get is to large to add it inline so I have it in this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QSbYgUoBkjGTkMJQX5PxQDarpadNU-QA/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to share your file, do not provide it in a link.

Comment: @jpsmith of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit more control (and a larger default legend) with `terra` (the replacement of `raster`)

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
plot(r)
plot(r, plg=list(cex=1.2))
```

As for the whitespace. As these are maps, the plots have a fixed aspect ratio. You can set the width of the canvas you are plotting on.

Comment: Thanks! I see it helps me with my problem with the colorbar, I´ll try to adapt my script to terra.